# Widget opening in a new window

Tags: php, html, moodle

I am trying this widget to open in a new window by adding "target="_blank" to the widget code:

but unfortunately it does not work.

Any ideas, suggestions ?  . Kindly appreciated

Comment: "target="_blank"   remove " before target like target="_blank"

Comment: May you have typo in your code. Try with `target = "_blank"`

Answer (score 0):

you are using extra `"` before target attribute

Use this

```
target="_blank"
```

Comment: Hi my friend, No I did not. I just tried to post the complete code here but my first time in this site. How can I post the code for you to see it?

Comment: create a fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/ with all your code and send link here so that we can see what you are doing